# VSCode, copy folder and file structure from source control (git) to local fs

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, plugins, version-control

I'm using VSCode in a project connected to GitLab. I'm using the `VSCode Git Graph` ([link](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph)) to manage source control on my GitLab remote project. 
For security reasons we're keeping in local file system all commits we're doing, but copy them by hand is frustrating. 
Is there a way to automatically copy the whole structure (folder, paths and files) of a commit into a local folder?

[image]

Let's say we have a situation like the image above: i need to create in a local folder the whole structure. So, by hand, I would create 
`routes_app/v2/configurations` putting in it `languages/english.json`, `languages/italian.json`,`configurations.json` and `README.md`. 
Then `routes_app/v2` and inside it `api.js`, `common.api.js` and so on. 
Is there a way to do it automatically? With a plugin maybe?

Comment: _"For security reasons we're keeping in local file system all commits we're doing, but copy them by hand is frustrating."_ - why? Isn't this the purpose of git?

Comment: We need to have them locally too

Comment: Git is local though?

Comment: @evolutionxbox what do you mean? We got the remote project connected to the local project....we do have local folders, but the reason for this question is to avoid copying all the modified files by hand

Answer (score 1):

Try this vs-code extension, it copies your project tree and saves it in a Read.me file in your root directory
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhucy.project-tree

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).